# Can't setup nginx proxy to docker container with react

Tags: reactjs, symfony, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to build web application based on docker containers and included usage of symfony and react. The problem is my container with nginx does not proxy my container with react running in development mode.Requests to backend by `/api/...` works as well, but when I'm trying to access to frontend `domain.com` for example, I'v got 502 error.

My **nginx** configuration:

```
upstream frontend {
  server frontend:8080;
}

server {
set $APP_ENV "dev";
set $APP_DEBUG "1";

listen 80;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
server_name store.com;
root /var/www/store/public;

location /api {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /oauth {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /_wdt {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /_profiler {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

# DEV
# This rule should only be placed on your development environment
# In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
location ~ ^/(index)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
    # current version of your application, you should pass the real
    # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
    # FPM.
    # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
    # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
    # for more information).
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
}

location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
}
location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
}

# return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
# this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass   http://frontend/;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
 }

error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

docker-compose

```
    version: '3'
services:
    php:
        build: php
        working_dir: /var/www/store
        links:
            - mysql
        volumes:
            - ../backend:/var/www/store
            - ./php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:ro
        networks:
            - backend
            - frontend
        environment:
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=192.168.31.32

    nginx:
        image: nginx
        links:
            - php
            - frontend
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        networks:
            - backend
            - frontend
        volumes:
            - ../backend:/var/www/store
            - ../frontend:/var/www/app
            - ./nginx/vhosts/dev/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro

    mysql:
        restart: always
        image: mysql:5.6
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        networks:
            - backend
        volumes:
            - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"

    frontend:
        image: node:latest
        user: node
        command: bash -c "npm install && npm start"
        working_dir: /home/node/app
        networks:
            - frontend
        volumes:
            - ../frontend:/home/node/app

networks:
    frontend:
    backend:

volumes:
    mysql-data:
```

Comment: Is you react app after `npm start` working on port `:80`? I think it should be by default `:3000` so then in you nginx you should have `proxy_pass   http://frontend:3000/;`. Nonetheless this configuration with `npm start` should be only used on development envionment. On production you should use static files generated by using `npm run build`

Comment: In location / your proxy pass uses `http://frontend`, but right at the top it says your frontend server listens on port 8080, so I would expect the value to be `prox_pass http://localhost:8080;`

Comment: @ttomalak when I run `docker-compose up` I could see from logs this message `Project is running at http://localhost:8080/` from frontend container. However I've tried to change port from 8080 to 3000 and it doesn't work

Comment: @dbrumann unfortunately it doesn't work, I've tried different combination of settings. with upstream directive, without it (as you suggested), always 502 error

Comment: Why you need to serve it by `start`? I think that there are may be some security restriction which are not allowing to serve react app via `npm start`  and then proxy_pass

Comment: @ttomalak because I use webpack for build my react app, and for development mode I use webpack dev server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in the nginx or docker configuration, the problem was in the configuration of webpack dev server. Resolved by using command `"start": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --inline --content-base"` for start dev server, and some additional config

```
devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
}
```